# jQuery .hover and .mouseleave Unintentional looping. How do I fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, image

What I'm looking to do:

1. Hover over  image, image fades Out.
2. Text  fade In after image fades Out.
3. Text fade-out with mouse-leave.
4. Original image fade-in.
5. End with original image and no text shown

**Problem:**

I have  the steps working, but they seem to keep looping, show the image and text flash on and off. Any suggestions?

```js
$("img").hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $("p").text("CHAIR").fadeIn(); 
});

$("p").mouseleave(function(){
    $("p").fadeOut();
    $("img").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
p {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;  
   left: 100px;
   top: 150px;
   font-size:45px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="chair" src="http://edufurniture.com/images/catalog/category13.jpg" alt="">
<p></p>
```

[jsfiddle example of steps 1 - 4](http://jsfiddle.net/xenodelmoto/L1ye4y1j/3/)

Comment: Your entire approach is wrong, but the image and the P inside another element, and attach the event handlers to that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L1ye4y1j/7/

Comment: @adeneo Why not an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  $(".foo").hover(
  function() {
    $('img',this).stop().fadeOut();
        $("p",this).text("CHAIR").stop().fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $('img',this).stop().fadeIn();
        $("p",this).text("CHAIR").stop().fadeOut();
  }
);


.foo {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
}
p {

   position: absolute;  
   left: 100px;
   top: 150px;
   font-size:45px;   
   }


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="foo"> <img id="chair" src="http://edufurniture.com/images/catalog/category13.jpg" alt="">
    <p></p>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L1ye4y1j/9/